# Django: filter by related model id list

Tags: django, django-models

Working from the follow django models:

```
class Position(models.Model):
    # pos_list in order ('P', 'C', '1B', '2B', '3B', 'SS', 'LF', 'CF', 'RF')
    # pos id / pk correspond to index value of pos_list.index(pos)
    pos = models.CharField(max_length=2)

class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    positions = models.ManyToManyField(Position, through='PlayerPosition')

class PlayerPosition(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
    position = models.ForeignKey(Position)
    primary = models.BooleanField()
```

If I have a list of position ids, e.g. `[3, 5]`, where `Position.objects.filter(id__in=[3,5])` would produce `['1B', '3B']`, I'd like to be able to filter `Player.objects.all()` by the position_id list of `[3, 5]` or some other combination of positions. In this example, I would want a list of all players who player either 1B (i.e. `Position.objects.get(id=3)`) or 3B (i.e. `Position.objects.get(id=5)`). How do I do this?

ANSWER:

```
Player.objects.filter(positions__id__in=[3,5])
```

SECOND ANSWER, because `__id` is unnecessary:

```
Player.objects.filter(positions__in=[3,5])
```

Any other comments would be great. Thanks, too-tired-to-code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
players = Player.objects.filter(positions__pk__in=[3,5])
```

Comment: Thanks! I beat you to it by a couple of minutes, but you still get full credit. `positions__pk__in` or `positions__id__in` seem both counter intuitive -- how can positions have a single id -- and intuitive -- if `__in` works then `positions` must have `__id`. Where is `positions__ids__in = [3,5]` when you need it?

Comment: Another note: the `__id` or `__pk` is unnecessary. `players = Player.object.filter(positions__in=[3,5])` is sufficient.